# Bash assignment value to variable as command substitution and print value output

Tags: bash, variables, echo, command-substitution

I would like to achieve this in Bash: `echo $(a=1)`and print the value of variable `a`

I test `eval`, `$$a`,`{}`, `$()` but none of them work as most of the times either I got literally `a=1` or in one case (I don't remember which) it tried to execute the value.

I known that I can do: `a=1;echo $a` but because I'm little fun one command per line (even if sometimes is getting little complicated) I was wondering if is possible to do this either with `echo` or with `printf`

Answer (score 3):

If you know that `$a` is previously unset, you can do this using the following syntax:

```
echo ${a:=1}
```

This, and other types of parameter expansion, are defined in the [POSIX shell command language specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02).

If you want to assign a numeric value, another option, which doesn't depend on the value previously being unset, would be to use an arithmetic expansion:

```
echo $(( a = 1 ))
```

This assigns the value and echoes the number that has been assigned.

It's worth mentioning that what you're trying to do cannot be done in a subshell *by design* because a child process cannot modify the environment of its parent.

Comment: The second I saw it also but if I will use this way (the all in one command) probably it will be a string. The first if I don't use `unset` makes it useful once. :(

Comment: You probably want `echo ${a:-1}`, which uses `1` for the expansion if `a` is unset (or set to the empty string), but doesn't set (or change) the value of `a`.

Comment: @chepner I was under the impression that the intent was to assign a new value to `$a` as well as print the new value (but I'm not 100%)

Comment: @TomFenech I think I'm misinterpreting his comment above.

Comment: @TomFenech yes, this is what I would like.

Comment: @Alex I'm afraid I don't think there's a way of doing what you're trying to do in a single statement.

Comment: @TomFenech Probably. It was a long shot but you never know.